# Excel Date Calculation with Rounding

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula, excel-2007

I am currently working on a report where i want to find out the months between 2 dates. I currently have this

=(DATEDIF(U224,V224,"m")+1)

However i want it to add another element where if the initial date is on or before the 15th of the month it will round down if it is 16th and after it will round up the month.

For example first date is 13th February and second date is 31st June. It will bring back 5 months. However if the first date is 20th February it will bring back 4 months.

Thanks in advance

Comment: June has 30 days btw

Comment: on or before the 15th of the month it will round down is not consistent with 13th February and second date is 31st June it will bring back 5 months and  first date is 20th February it will bring back 4 months. Here you have "rounded" down when > 15.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are saying:

```
=IF(DAY(U224)<16,DATEDIF(U224,V224,"m"),DATEDIF(U224,V224,"m")+1)
```